# Broadcasting audio live for Android and Mac

Tags: android, ios, html, audio, broadcasting

Does anybody know how to broadcast live audio to a website so people can listen in Android devices and Apple? I know how to use SAM Broadcaster but they only have a Flash player which is not supported well in Android.

Comment: For iOS there's [HTTP Live Streaming](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/)

Comment: Thanks, Do you know about Android too?

Answer (score 1):

I heard that the guys from Primcast.com have a player that works on all mobile devices if you have an account with them and you are streaming mp3 !